# How to merge multiple netcdf files in R and open it Arc Map?

Tags: r, arcgis, netcdf

I have several netCDF files with one variable that I need to merge into one netCDF file and open it in Arc Map.The following are the examples of the file name that I use.
2005.nc
2006.nc
2007.nc
2008.nc
2009.nc
2010.nc
2011.nc
.......
I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux or macOS it is better to do this using CDO as follows:

```
cdo mergetime 20*.nc outfile
```

which will merge the files.

As a side point, please show evidence of your attempts (as SO asks) before asking questions.